# Using current limiting for motor

Tags: current-limiting

I bought Johnson motors for making bot and its max load current is 9A.My batterys are 12V 1.3AH. I gotta problem with my motor driver circuit.It has L293D(2A peak). If load increases on motor current may increase damaging the IC so I am thinking to limit current drawn by motor to 1.8A. Will it work even if load increases and only 2A current is provided? Will Any of the component get damaged?What should i do? Thanks..

Comment: There would be no damage to the motor if you limit the current to 1.8 A.  Your motors are capable of over 100 W peak, but you want to limit them to 22 W, what a waste. .....why would you not buy smaller, lighter, lower current motors.

Comment: @JackCreasey thanks for reply and sorry for me being so careless while selecting motors. i thaught i might use these motors for a lower rank competition n then use same for wars or good robot competition. now am stuck thinking if motors might get damaged by providing it limiting its current than it wants